# upload php files to google cloud using lamp

Tags: google-app-engine

I am new to google cloud. I am using xamp in my laptop. I have created a project in php called "test" in my htdocs. Its works succesfully on my localhost. I have an account at google cloud and I have setup lamp and it works successfully. I was trying to find a way to upload my folder "test" (which includes all my php files) to google cloud. Do I need to use Google App Engine Launcher? Is there an easier way to do this? i.e example to use filezilla? Anybody knows where I can find a tutorial about how to do this? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to download Google App Engine SDK for PHP from [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/downloads#Google_App_Engine_SDK_for_PHP). Detailed procedure for uploading and managing PHP app in Google App Engine is described [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/tools/uploadinganapp).

Comment: That is for PHP app and PHP app has nothing to do with LAMP Stack First link is OK but second link should be this [link](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/lamp/transfer-files)